# How to compute $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(k))$ via Dolbeault cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

In algebraic geometry, the cohomology groups $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(k))$ are well-understood. As far as I know, in most textbooks these cohomology groups are computed via Cech cohomology or Koszul resolutions.

> > My question is: in the case of $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$, could we compute $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathcal{O}(k))$ analytically via Dolbeault cohomology? Is there any references？

Comment: Wouldn’t you just twist the cotangent bundle by $\mathcal{O}(k)$ and compute using the usual $\overline{\partial}_{\mathcal{O}(k)}$ resolution?